# How to count rows from previous query

Tags: php, mysql

This code is a filter that show results from a TABLE using a input text and a input submit

```
QUERY 1

if(isset($_POST['btn_search'])){
        $buscar_text=$_POST['search'];
        $select_buscar=$con->prepare('
            SELECT * FROM curso WHERE NOMBRE LIKE :campo OR AREA LIKE :campo;'
        );
        $select_buscar->execute(array(
            ':campo' =>"%".$buscar_text."%"
        ));
        $resultado=$select_buscar->fetchAll();
    }
```

How count rows based in that query only and not in all the TABLE of data base?

This code count the rows of all the TABLE ... I want that count in the results of the first query only.

```
QUERY 2

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM curso WHERE NOMBRE = 'Andrea' AND AREA = 'Gramática'"; 
    $result = $con->prepare($sql); 
    $result->execute(); 
    $resultcount = $result->fetchColumn();
```

Thanks!

Comment: "This code count the rows of all the TABLE" -- No it doesn't. It counts only the rows satisfying the `WHERE` clause. Just use the same `WHERE` clause like in the other query (Note that they're not only different regarding the values, also the operator is `AND` in one and `OR` in the other) together with `count()` (and without `*`) and you'll get number of rows that query would return without `count()` (but `*`).

Comment: For the first query, `fetchAll()` returns an array, the number of rows is the length of the array